# Visual Studio Code autocomplete static names

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, ide, webstorm

Is there any extension that autocompletes exported static variables, static functions, enums? Examples: [image]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Here is how it works in Webstorm:

[image: 4]
[image: 5]

Comment: i see only ads/junk, no screenshots

Comment: My bad, I use an adblocker so I didn't notice. I will edit now